# Selecting MySql table data into an array using PDO class?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, pdo

I have found some info here, but can comment to ask additional info. So my problem is:
I want to select my data from mySQL.
I have two tables:
customers (id,name,ak,numeris) 
prekes (id, customer_id, prek_name, prek_value)

id in both tables is auto incremented.

I try to fill array?

I have only one value passed (customers.id). there are 5 records with same prekes.customer_id.

```
$pdo = Database::connect();
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM prekes WHERE customer_id=' . $pirkejas . ''; //$pirkejas = id passed via $_POST.
$q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
    //      if ($row['prek_pav'] != '') {
    $prekes = array($row['prek_name'], $row['prek_value']);

    Database::disconnect();
```

How to fill array $prekes in correct way?

Edit:

I want to print value in my form:

```
<table class="table-bordered">
<tr>
<td><input class="input-medium" name="prekes[1][pavadinimas]" type="text"  placeholder="Prekė" value=""></td>
<td><input class="input-medium" name="prekes[1][kaina]" type="text"  placeholder="Kaina" value=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input class="input-medium" name="prekes[2][pavadinimas]" type="text"  placeholder="Prekė" value=""></td>
<td><input class="input-medium" name="prekes[2][kaina]" type="text"  placeholder="Kaina" value=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input class="input-medium" name="prekes[3][pavadinimas]" type="text"  placeholder="Prekė" value=""></td>
<td><input class="input-medium" name="prekes[3][kaina]" type="text"  placeholder="Kaina" value=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input class="input-medium" name="prekes[4][pavadinimas]" type="text"  placeholder="Prekė" value=""></td>
```

I my action does:

```
$pdo = Database::connect();
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO customers (name,pavarde,ak,data, numeris) values(?, ?, ?, ?,?)";
    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array($name, $pavarde, $ak, date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time()), $numeris));

    $pirkejo_id = $pdo->lastInsertId();

    foreach ($prekes as $preke) {
        //prekiu uzpildymas
        $sql = "INSERT INTO prekes (customer_id,prek_name,prek_value) values(?, ?, ?)";
        $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array($pirkejo_id, $preke['pavadinimas'], $preke['kaina']));
    }

    Database::disconnect();
    header("Location: default.php");
```

I don't know how to get all values from database,

Comment: depends on what you consider to be "the correct way". What do you want the array to look like exactly ?

Comment: I updated my question. I am making this array to set values in input forn to edit them and put to database again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't inject values into your SQL queries. Use parameter binding instead.

```
$q = $pdo->prepare('SELECT id, prek_name, prek_value FROM prekes WHERE customer_id = ?');
$q->execute([$pirkejas]); // if PHP < 5.4, use array($pirkejas)
$prekes = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Now `$prekes` will be an array of rows where each row is an associative array.

```
<?php foreach ($prekes as $row) : ?>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input name="prekes[<?= (int) $row['id'] ?>][pavadinimas]"
               value="<?= htmlspecialchars($row['prek_name']) ?>">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name="prekes[<?= (int) $row['id'] ?>][kaina]"
               value="<?= htmlspecialchars($row['prek_value']) ?>">
    </td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: How were his quotes messed up? He had an unnecessary ` . ''` at the end, but they didn't hurt anything.

Comment: @Barmar Removed that note. I see two single quotes and I think SQL escaping :)

Answer (score 1):

PDO has a method that does this for you. Also, you shouldn't substitute variables directly into the query, you should use parameters.

```
$q = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM prekes WHERE customer_id= :id');
$q->execute(array(':id' => $pirkejas));
$prekes = $q->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Fixed it -- it's so easy to get mixed up between PDO and mysqli.

Comment: I think he meant you are not checking the return value of execute, to see if the query failed.  if( $q && $q->execute() ) $prekes = $q->fetchAll();

Comment: The question has ERRMODE_EXCEPTION set, so I don't think it's necessary to test it.

Comment: In general it isn't, but ERRMODE_EXCEPTION only throws on an error.  Sometime a failed query isn't an error, or at least that has been my experience.  i.e.  execute returns false, but errorInfo() returns no error codes (looks successful).

Comment: I think you may be confusing queries that return no rows with queries that get an error.

Comment: No, and maybe its a a bug in PDO for edge cases or maybe it was the mysql driver, I donno, but I've experienced it. execute fails, and nothing in errorInfo.  No rows returns successful execute.

Comment: There aren't many reasons for `execute()` to fail as errors are usually covered in the *prepare* stage. Only thing that comes to mind is a parameter count mismatch which certainly does throw an exception.

Comment: There are actually a lot of cases, 2 of which, database doesn't exist, or table doesn't exist, as this can't be verified at the prepare statement level for most drivers, some mismatches can pass the prepare level for a bad formatted embedded query that fails the execute.  Like I said, it could be an edge case for the query i was using, or a bug in the mysql driver itself.